# pub get not generating pubspec.lock file

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I have a new 2016 MacBook Pro 13-inch, and am trying to get dart and dartium up and running for work. However, when I run `pub get` in the directory with pubspec.yaml, I do not get a pubspec.lock file, or anything else for that matter.

The packages claim to be downloading, but then after the last package, I receive no further output.

here is the output of `pub get`

```
RMTMACSIERRA01:ui jacob.massengill$ pub get
Resolving dependencies... (10.3s) 
+ analyzer 0.25.2+1 (0.30.0+2 available)
+ angular 1.1.2+2
+ angular_ui 0.6.13
+ args 0.12.2+6 (0.13.7 available)
+ async 1.9.0 (1.13.3 available)
+ barback 0.15.2+7 (0.15.2+11 available)
+ browser 0.10.0+2
+ charcode 1.1.1
+ cli_util 0.0.1+2 (0.1.1 available)
+ code_transformers 0.2.9+3 (0.5.1+3 available)
+ collection 1.1.3 (1.14.1 available)
+ convert 1.1.0 (2.0.1 available)
+ crypto 0.9.2+1 (2.0.1 available)
+ csslib 0.13.7+1 (0.14.0 available)
+ dart_config 0.5.0
+ dart_style 0.2.1 (1.0.6 available)
+ dart_to_js_script_rewriter 1.0.1 (1.0.2 available)
+ di 3.3.5+1 (3.3.10 available)
+ glob 1.1.3
+ guinness 0.1.18
+ html 0.12.2+2 (0.13.2 available)
+ html5lib 0.12.1
+ http_multi_server 2.0.3
+ http_parser 2.2.1 (3.1.1 available)
+ initialize 0.6.1+2 (0.6.2+6 available)
+ intl 0.8.10+4 (0.15.0 available)
+ js 0.6.0 (0.6.1 available)
+ logging 0.11.3+1
+ matcher 0.12.0+2 (0.12.1+1 available)
+ meta 1.0.5
+ mime 0.9.3
+ mixpanel 1.0.0
+ mock 0.11.0+4 (0.12.0 available)
+ mockito 0.8.2 (2.0.2 available)
+ observe 0.13.1+3 (0.15.1 available)
+ package_config 0.1.5 (1.0.1 available)
+ path 1.4.1
+ perf_api 0.0.9 (0.1.0 available)
+ petitparser 1.5.3 (1.5.4 available)
+ plugin 0.1.0 (0.2.0 available)
+ pool 1.3.0 (1.3.1 available)
+ pub_semver 1.3.2
+ quiver 0.21.4 (0.25.0 available)
+ route_hierarchical 0.6.2 (0.7.0 available)
+ shelf 0.6.5 (0.6.7+2 available)
+ shelf_static 0.2.4
+ shelf_web_socket 0.0.1+5 (0.2.1 available)
+ smoke 0.3.5 (0.3.6+3 available)
+ source_map_stack_trace 1.0.4 (1.1.4 available)
+ source_maps 0.10.4
+ source_span 1.4.0
+ stack_trace 1.7.3
+ stream_channel 1.3.1 (1.6.1 available)
+ string_scanner 0.1.5 (1.0.2 available)
+ test 0.12.7 (0.12.21 available)
+ typed_data 1.1.3
+ unittest 0.11.7 (0.12.4+1 available)
+ utf 0.9.0+3
+ uuid 0.5.1 (0.5.3 available)
+ watcher 0.9.7 (0.9.7+3 available)
+ web_components 0.11.4 (0.12.5 available)
+ webdriver 1.0.0 (1.2.3 available)
+ when 0.2.0
+ which 0.1.3
+ xml 2.2.3 (2.5.0 available)
+ xml2json 2.0.6 (2.0.8 available)
+ yaml 2.1.10 (2.1.12 available)
Downloading angular 1.1.2+2...
Downloading angular_ui 0.6.13...
Downloading args 0.12.2+6...
Downloading browser 0.10.0+2...
Downloading dart_config 0.5.0...
Downloading dart_to_js_script_rewriter 1.0.1...
Downloading glob 1.1.3...
Downloading guinness 0.1.18...
Downloading js 0.6.0...
Downloading mixpanel 1.0.0...
Downloading mock 0.11.0+4...
Downloading mockito 0.8.2...
Downloading quiver 0.21.4...
Downloading test 0.12.7...
Downloading uuid 0.5.1...
Downloading web_components 0.11.4...
Downloading webdriver 1.0.0...
Downloading xml2json 2.0.6...
Downloading yaml 2.1.10...
Downloading charcode 1.1.1...
Downloading html 0.12.2+2...
Downloading shelf_web_socket 0.0.1+5...
Downloading perf_api 0.0.9...
Downloading pub_semver 1.3.2...
Downloading source_map_stack_trace 1.0.4...
Downloading pool 1.3.0...
Downloading http_multi_server 2.0.3...
Downloading string_scanner 0.1.5...
Downloading source_span 1.4.0...
Downloading http_parser 2.2.1...
Downloading stream_channel 1.3.1...
Downloading route_hierarchical 0.6.2...
Downloading shelf_static 0.2.4...
Downloading convert 1.1.0...
Downloading typed_data 1.1.3...
Downloading matcher 0.12.0+2...
Downloading collection 1.1.3...
Downloading utf 0.9.0+3...
Downloading initialize 0.6.1+2...
Downloading async 1.9.0...
Downloading xml 2.2.3...
Downloading dart_style 0.2.1...
Downloading petitparser 1.5.3...
Downloading mime 0.9.3...
Downloading shelf 0.6.5...
Downloading code_transformers 0.2.9+3...
Downloading cli_util 0.0.1+2...
Downloading which 0.1.3...
Downloading when 0.2.0...
Downloading path 1.4.1...
Downloading crypto 0.9.2+1...
Downloading di 3.3.5+1...
Downloading barback 0.15.2+7...
Downloading html5lib 0.12.1...
Downloading observe 0.13.1+3...
Downloading smoke 0.3.5...
Downloading source_maps 0.10.4...
Downloading logging 0.11.3+1...
Downloading csslib 0.13.7+1...
Downloading stack_trace 1.7.3...
Downloading intl 0.8.10+4...
Downloading meta 1.0.5...
Downloading unittest 0.11.7...
Downloading analyzer 0.25.2+1...
Downloading plugin 0.1.0...
Downloading package_config 0.1.5...
Downloading watcher 0.9.7...
```

and then when I try to run `pub build` or `pub serve`,

```
no pubspec.lock file found, please run "pub get" first
```

I installed dart 1.15.0 (the version my team uses) via homebrew.

EDIT: my supervisor clone my forked repo, and was able to execute `pub get` and `pub serve` without issue, so there doesn't appear to be an issue with the pubspec.yaml file or the repo itself.

Comment: How is that related to `angularjs`?

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake, will remove that tag

Comment: It looks like `pub get` didn't complete. There was a recent bug AFAIR that there is no error message even though it failed at some point.

Comment: Try `pub get -v`

Comment: unfortunately, the output is too long

Comment: Does it say "completed successfully" (or similar) at the end of the output?

Comment: nope, the last thing it says is 

   ` FINE: HTTP GET 
    https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/web_components/versions/0.11.4.tar.gz
    | user-agent: Dart pub 1.15.0`
of note though, is that it hangs for a good 5-10 seconds after that is printed

Comment: I think that's the issue I mentioned above. I think the network connection times out and then `pub` just exits without an error. Please check the `pub` github repo for the issue (it might be fixed already)

Comment: I am a new employee, is it possible it's an authentication error on my end causing the timeout?

Comment: I thought I had seen it event today or yesterday but I couldn't find the issue myself. I'm out of ideas :-/

Comment: no problem, thank you for your help. I am going to look around on github for that issue. I suspect it may be a firewall thing now.

Answer (score 1):

After adding pub to the allowed connections in my firewall settings, and performing a hard reboot of my computer, this issue has been resolved.

I believe the issue was caused by pub getting a connection timeout due to the firewall, and failing without warning.

Comment: I've had some issues that were similar where after a restart they're resolved.